# Bucle Infinito en C#

Tags: c#, poo

Estoy realizando un código de un juego de role, en mi caso soy el encargado de modelar el campo de batalla, cuándo inicializo los objetos(enemigos y heroes) y los hago pelear con el metodo `DoEncounter()`.

Por alguna razón se me genera un bucle infinito, quisiera saber como podría solucionarlo, probé quitar la variable booleana del bucle foreach la cuál la uso para invertir el orden  mi código de la clase `CampodeBatalla` es este:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace RolePLay
{
    public class CampodeBatalla
    {
        public List<Personaje> ListaEnemigos;
        public List<Personaje> ListaPersonajes;
        private bool EnemigosPrimero;
        public CampodeBatalla(List<Personaje> ListaEnemigos, List<Personaje> ListaPersonajes)
        {
            this.ListaEnemigos = ListaEnemigos;
            this.ListaPersonajes = ListaPersonajes;
        }
        public void DoEncounter()
        {
            // defino una variable booleana en la que si es true se ejecuta
            EnemigosPrimero = true;
            // el ciclo en el que los enemigos atacan primero, si es false 
            // se ejecuta el ciclo en el que los heroes atacan primero, después lo invierto con !
            while (ListaEnemigos.Count > 0 && ListaPersonajes.Count > 0)
            {
                // Los enemigos atacan a los hérores primero
                if (EnemigosPrimero)
                {
                    foreach (var Enemigo in ListaEnemigos)
                    {
                        if (ListaPersonajes.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Personaje Heroe = ListaPersonajes[0];
                            Atacar(Enemigo, Heroe);
                            if (Heroe.Salud <= 0)
                            {
                                ListaPersonajes.RemoveAt(0);
                                // si la salud del persona(Heroe) es menor a 0 lo remuevo de la lista
                                // uso el método RemoveAt de la clase collections generic
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    // ahora los heroes atacan a los enemigos
                    foreach (var Heroe in ListaPersonajes)
                    {
                        if (ListaEnemigos.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (Personaje Enemigo in ListaEnemigos)
                            {
                                if (Enemigo.Salud <= 0)
                                // si la salud del Enemigo es menor a 0 lo remuevo de la lista
                                {
                                    Atacar(Heroe, Enemigo);
                                    {
                                        Heroe.ContadorVP += Enemigo.VP;
                                        ListaEnemigos.Remove(Enemigo);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                {
                                    foreach (Personaje heroe in ListaPersonajes)
                                    {
                                        if (Heroe.ContadorVP >= 5) // lógica de curación.
                                        {
                                            Heroe.Salud = 100;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    EnemigosPrimero = !EnemigosPrimero;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        private void Atacar(Personaje Enemigo, Personaje Heroe)
        {
            //Lógica, atacan los enemigos
            if (EnemigosPrimero)
            {
                if (ListaPersonajes.Count == 1)
                {
                    // si hay un solo heroe, todos los enemigos atacan al mismo heroe
                    Heroe.Salud -= Enemigo.ObtenerAtaque(); // le resto la salud de mi heroe al ataque del enemigo
                    System.Console.WriteLine($ "El enemigo atacó al heroe, salud del heroe {Heroe.Salud}");
                }
            }
            {
                if (ListaPersonajes.Count != 1)
                {
                    int IndiceEnemigo = ListaEnemigos.IndexOf(Enemigo);
                    int IndiceHeroe = IndiceEnemigo % ListaPersonajes.Count;
                    Personaje HeroeAtacado = ListaPersonajes[IndiceHeroe];
                    HeroeAtacado.Salud -= Enemigo.ObtenerAtaque();
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Enemigo" + IndiceEnemigo + "Ataca al Heroe" + IndiceHeroe + "Salud Del Heroe: " + HeroeAtacado.Salud);
                }
                else
                {
                    Enemigo.Salud -= Heroe.ObtenerAtaque();
                    System.Console.WriteLine($ "El Héroe ataca al enemigo, salud del Enemigo{Enemigo.Salud}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: segui tu codigo.. definitivamente las dos listas no quedan nunca vacias...

Comment: Si bien ahora que edité tu pregunta el código se ve mejor, tienes demasiado código y texto en tus funciones. Más funciones (sin exagerar) con menos código hacen que sea más fácil de leer. Los comentarios ayudan a entender lo que hace el código, pero realmente agregan ruido. Lo mejor es reducirlos al mínimo o que el código se pueda entender sin comentarios.

Comment: Siguiendo mi comentario anterior, tienes varios comentarios triviales. Por ejemplo *si la salud del persona(Heroe) es menor a 0 lo remuevo de la lista uso el método RemoveAt de la clase collections generic*. Te toma más palabras describir lo que hace ese trozo de código que el código en sí.

Comment: Tenes razón, pero el código está hecho en un entorno universitario más que nada para explicarles a mis compañeros que hace cada cosa, es redundante sí, pero hay que partir de la base de que no tienen muchos conocimientos previos.

Comment: Si tengo que hacer scroll horizontal para leer el código, significa que no es buen código. Si tus compañeros no tienen conocimientos previos, es como un lienzo en blanco, no lo llenes de garabatos. Qué mejor momento para mostrarles Clean Code y principios SOLID. Saludos

Comment: El bucle es infinito porque cuando `EnemigosPrimero==true` entra en el primer `if` y en ese if nunca haces `EnemigosPrimero = !EnemigosPrimero;`. Además como te han dicho arriba, tu código está muy desordenado y no se entiende que hace, abusas de las anidaciones, personalmente me gustaría ayudarte a ordenarlo, pero para eso sería necesario que explicaras la lógica de los ataques, por ejemplo entiendo que los enemigos atacan al primer héroe hasta matarlo, luego pasan al siguiente. Pero en el caso de que los héroes ataquen no se entiende que pasa.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!, soy nuevo programando y por ende inexperto, eso no es excusa, por eso voy a mejorar!

Comment: la lógica de ataque es esta : Los enemigos atacan primero. Cada enemigo ataca únicamente a un héroe. Si hay un sólo héroe, todos los enemigos atacan al mismo. Si hay más de un enemigo y más de un héroe, el primer enemigo ataca al primer héroe, el segundo enemigo ataca al segundo héroe, y así sucesivamente. Si hay menos héroes (N) que enemigos (M), el siguiente enemigo (N+1) ataca al primero héroe, el siguiente enemigo (N+2) ataca al segundo héroe, y así sucesivamente.

Luego, los héroes sobrevivientes atacan a los enemigos. Todos los héroes atacan a cada uno de los enemigos 1 vez.

Comment: Cada vez que un héroe mata a un enemigo, ese héroe se lleva los VP del enemigo que ha vencido.

Se repite el primer punto.

El encuentro termina cuando todos los héroes o todos los enemigos han muerto. Si un héroe ha conseguido 5+ (5 o más) VP, se cura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios el problema del bucle infinito se debe a que en la primera interacción `EnemigosPrimero==true`, donde entra a un `if` que nunca cambia a `EnemigosPrimero = !EnemigosPrimero;`

Pero tal y como te lo han hecho ver en los comentarios tu problema más grande está en el orden y legibilidad del código (y te lo dice una persona que es muy desordenada). Ahora bien, es del todo normal programar al inicio de forma desordenada (de hecho yo he visto profesionales con peor código que el tuyo), aquí la experiencia es clave, así que mientras antes comiences a preocuparte de este tema, antes mejorarás.

Basta de blabla y vamos a lo importante.

A mi me parece que tu algoritmo no funciona como has descrito en los comentarios (si es que interpreté correctamente tus palabras), cuando los enemigos atacan primero y el héroe no muere, el segundo enemigo vuelve a atacar al primer héroe

Yo voy a reducir el problema para dar un ejemplo

Veamos el siguiente caso:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Herores = new List<string>() { "H1", "H2", "H3" };
    var Enemigos = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2", "E3" };
            
    for (int i = 0; i < Enemigos.Count; i++)
    {
        var enemigo = Enemigos[i];
        var heroe = Herores[i % Herores.Count()];

        Console.WriteLine(enemigo + " Ataca a -> " + heroe);
    }
}
```

Aquí tenemos igual número de héroes y enemigos, y por consola se imprime

```
E1 Ataca a -> H1
E2 Ataca a -> H2
E3 Ataca a -> H3
```

Ahora veamos con más enemigos que héroes

```
var Herores = new List<string>() { "H1", "H2", "H3" };
var Enemigos = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5" };
```

```
E1 Ataca a -> H1
E2 Ataca a -> H2
E3 Ataca a -> H3
E4 Ataca a -> H1
E5 Ataca a -> H2
```

Y por último menos enemigos que heroes

```
var Herores = new List<string>() { "H1", "H2", "H3" };
var Enemigos = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2"};
```

```
E1 Ataca a -> H1
E2 Ataca a -> H2
```

Como verás todo el truco del algoritmo está en el índice `[i % Herores.Count()]`, que hace que cuando llega al final del largo de la lista, vuelva al inicio

Ahora llevemos está lógica a tu código

Lo primero es que en el "Campo de batalla" hay 2 grupos y al Campo de batalla no le debe importar quien es heroe o enemigo, éste solo se encarga que combatan. Por esta razón hay lógica que debe llevarse a la clase Personaje, como el asunto de los `VP`, como yo no tengo idea que más lógica tiene el juego, creé unas clases sencillas

```
public class Personaje 
{
    public int Salud { get; set; }
    public int VP { get; set; }
    public int Ataque { get; set; }
    public int ObtenerAtaque() => Ataque;

    public virtual void Atacar(Personaje victima)
    {
        victima.Salud -= ObtenerAtaque();
    }
   
}

public class Heroe : Personaje
{
    public override void Atacar(Personaje victima)
    {
        base.Atacar(victima);
        if(victima.Salud <= 0)
        {
            this.VP += victima.VP;
        }
    }
}
```

Una clase Personaje, que funciona para los enemigos y otra Heroe que hereda de Personaje y a su vez cambia la función `Atacar`. Y claro ahora cada Personaje tiene su función de ataque

Luego la clase CampoBatalla queda algo así:

```
public class CampodeBatalla
{
    public List<Personaje> ListaEnemigos;
    public List<Personaje> ListaHeores;
    private bool EnemigosPrimero = true;
    public CampodeBatalla(IEnumerable<Personaje> ListaEnemigos, IEnumerable<Personaje> ListaHeores)
    {
        this.ListaEnemigos = ListaEnemigos.ToList();
        this.ListaHeores = ListaHeores.ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Funcion que hace atacar a un grupo contra otro
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Atacantes">Grupo que ataca</param>
    /// <param name="Atacados">Grupo que es atacado</param>
    /// <returns>Retorna una lista de los muertos</returns>
    public List<Personaje> Atacar(List<Personaje> Atacantes, List<Personaje> Atacados)
    {
        var muertos = new List<Personaje>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Atacantes.Count; i++)
        {
            var atacante = Atacantes[i];
            var inidiceAtacado = i % Atacados.Count();
            var atacado = Atacados[inidiceAtacado];

            atacante.Atacar(atacado);

            Console.WriteLine($"{GetTipoAtaca()} {i} ataca a {GetTipoVictima()} {inidiceAtacado}, la salud del {GetTipoVictima()} es de: {atacado.Salud}");

            if (atacado.Salud <= 0)
            {
                muertos.Add(atacado);
                Console.WriteLine($"El {GetTipoVictima()} {inidiceAtacado} ha muerto");

            }
        }
        return muertos;
    }


    public void DoEncounter()
    {
        while (ListaEnemigos.Count > 0 && ListaHeores.Count > 0)
        {
            var orden = GetOrdenAtaque();
            var muertos = Atacar(orden.atacante, orden.atacado);
                
            orden.atacado.RemoveAll(muertos.Contains);

            if (!EnemigosPrimero) //recuperar vida
            {
                CurarHeroes();
                Console.WriteLine("Heroes recuperan Salud");
            }
            EnemigosPrimero = !EnemigosPrimero;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("FIN");
    }


    private void CurarHeroes()
    {
        foreach (var h in ListaHeores.Where(a => a.VP >= 5))
        {
            h.Salud = 100;
        }
    }
        /// <summary>
        /// Esta función se encarga de entregar 2 listas, los que atacan y los que son atacados.Esto 
        /// dependiente de la variable EnemigosPrimero
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Tupla de (atacante,atacado)</returns>
    private (List<Personaje> atacante, List<Personaje> atacado) GetOrdenAtaque()
        => EnemigosPrimero switch
        {
            true => (ListaEnemigos, ListaHeores),
            false => (ListaHeores, ListaEnemigos)
        };

    private string GetTipoAtaca()  => EnemigosPrimero switch
    {
            true => "Enemigo",
            false => "Heroe"
    };
    private string GetTipoVictima() => EnemigosPrimero switch
    {
        true => "Heroe",
        false => "Enemigo"
    };
}
```

Fíjate en que ahora toda las funciones caben en media pantalla, que no hay tantas anidaciones de `{}`. Para esto tu vas creando funciones utilitarias que te ayuden a ordenar el código

La verdad no se si esto te va a funcionar 100% con la lógica de tu juego, y es lo que menos me importa. Lo principal es que captures la idea de orden de un programa, que veas que es importante separar en funciones. Evidentemente este código se puede mejorar mucho más. C# tiene muchas otras funciones y azúcar sintáctico que ayudan a la legibilidad del código, por mi parte no quise ahondar más porque creo que se me pasó la mano con algunas conceptos que quizás escapen de tu conocimiento, de todas maneras ante cualquier duda, me preguntas yo feliz en responder.